# Remove all events from DoubleTap Map control (WP8)

Tags: events, windows-phone-8, controls

I have problem with one thing in WP8 Map control. I can't remove standart DoubleTap event which zoom  map. Finally I want override this event by my own written in MainPage class, but now during double tapping Map invoke zooming and my event together... I added event by `map.DoubleTap += MyEvent`, but I can't get delegate's list from this event to clear DoubleTap. I also often get error `"The event UIElement.DoubleTap can only appear on the left hand side of += or -="`, which don't allow me to assign object. 

I'm very frustrated because of this problem. I will be glad if someone will help me with this problem :).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you'll be able to override the `DoubleTap` event.

[How do I Manually Invoke/Raise Mouse Events in Silverlight 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3250604/)