# How to stay in and change the current Silverlight URL window

Tags: silverlight

In regards to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5964026/1312672) question:

```
<HyperlinkButton NavigateUri="http://www.microsoft.com" Content="Go to Microsoft" TargetName="_blank"/>
```

This opens a new window or tab to a external URL. The External URL navigation is correct, but how can we stay in the same window and tab?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if using HyperLinkButton, set TargetName to "_self" will open link in current page.

Answer from:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/silverlightdevtools/thread/250d546a-3237-4f7d-a146-b31e58191adf/

Comment: Or from [TargetName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.windows.controls.hyperlinkbutton.targetname(v=vs.95).aspx) doc :) it's work like [Html target](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_target.asp) attribute. The default value "" is like "_self".