# How to simulate the Click functionality of the Windows simple "Button" using C#

Tags: c#, silverlight, testing, automated-tests, ui-automation

How to simulate the Click functionality of the Windows simple "Button" using C#?
I'm writing testcases for the functionality of Button Click. Code is resided in different projects. Somehow I got the button control which i need with the Button Name property. Now only thing i need is triggering/invoking  '`Click`' action. The code relates to the Button_Click event handler is resided altogether in different project/solution. As I'm working on Silverlight UI testing by writing testcases with Assert statements. I need to simulate or invoke the simple Windows Button '`Click`' action. Please help!

Comment: check if this [article](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/mahesh/programmatically-trigger-events-of-a-control-in-silverlight/) can help, he used System.Windows.Automation.

Comment: see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/186553/sending-a-mouse-click-to-a-button-in-silverlight-2

Comment: Sorry to say that both of your comments didn't help with my expected result. As I need simulation of click functionality.

Comment: What's the problem with user2720372's suggestion? It does emulate the click functionality using UI Automation.

Comment: Is this a Silverlight button you are trying to click or a windows form button?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is an elegant a solution as you are looking for, but we typically user AutoIt scripting when doing these types of actions, you can read all about it here

http://www.autoitscript.com/site/

Answer (score 1):

you can use UI Automation Framework by Microsoft very easily to do that.

Get to the `AutomationElement` represnting the button and by using it's `Invoke Pattern`.

then, simply  call the Method `Invoke()` and there you have it! the click is done!

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're after a UI test. Microsoft's [Coded UI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd286726.aspx) framework would be your best bet.

With a Coded UI test, you can record actions against your UI and add assertions to verify that the UI is behaving properly. When you execute the test, it actually launches the application and plays back the actions you recorded to get the application to the expected state.

Naturally, UI tests are best used sparingly since they're a lot slower. A reasonable unit test should take a few milliseconds to run, but pretty much any UI test is going to take several orders of magnitude longer.

Ideally, you use a UI test only to validate the user-facing functionality of the application. For example, "When I click the 'Foo' button, the 'Bar' box turns red."