# HTML Silverlight bridge and WriteableBitmap

Tags: javascript, c#, html, silverlight, writeablebitmap

I'm trying to implement the [Silverlight HTML Bridge](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645076(v=vs.95).aspx) and the function is not executing properly when triggered from the HTML side.

I am using Silverlight 5.

### Problem

I have reduced the example to rendering a rectangle on a [`WriteableBitmap`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Windows.Media.Imaging.WriteableBitmap(v=vs.95).aspx). My actual code will be doing pixel manipulations using the [`Pixels` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.writeablebitmap.pixels(v=vs.95).aspx).

When the Silverlight button is clicked, the function executes and the image shows the rendered rectangle. When the HTML button is clicked, the function still executes but the image does not show anything.

I can verify by debugging with breakpoints that the parameters are passed in correctly and the function does actually execute when either button is clicked. The only difference is the rendering of the image.

I have also tried to use the code in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3095409/404623) to trigger the Silverlight button to click. The event is triggered and the function executes but again, nothing is rendered.

### Code

#### HTML page

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Page1</title>
    <script src="Silverlight.js"></script>
    <script>
        function onSilverlightError(sender, args) {
            // autogenerated things
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <button id="go" type="button">Button in HTML</button>
    <div id="silverlightControlHost">
        <object data="data:application/x-silverlight-2," type="application/x-silverlight-2" width="100%" height="100%">
            <param name="source" value="ClientBin/dynamicbitmap.xap">
            <param name="onError" value="onSilverlightError">
            <param name="onLoad" value="pluginLoaded">
        </object>
        <iframe id="_sl_historyFrame" style="visibility:hidden;height:0px;width:0px;border:0px"></iframe>
    </div>
    <script>
        var slCtl = null;
        function pluginLoaded(sender, args) {
            slCtl = sender.getHost();
        }

        document.getElementById('go').attachEvent('onclick', function () {
            slCtl.Content.MainPage.doThings(300, 300);
        });
    </script>
```

#### MainPage.xaml

```xml
<UserControl x:Class="dynamicbitmap.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="400">

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
        <Button HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Content="Button in Silverlight" Height="23" Name="button1" Width="150" Click="button1_Click" />
        <Image HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="image1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0, 30, 0, 0" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

#### MainPage.xaml.cs

```csharp
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

using System.Windows.Browser;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;

namespace dynamicbitmap
{
    public partial class MainPage : UserControl
    {
        WriteableBitmap bm;

        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        [ScriptableMember()]
        public void doThings(int width, int height)
        {
            bm = new WriteableBitmap(width, height);
            image1.Source = bm;

            Rectangle rect = new Rectangle();
            rect.Width = 250;
            rect.Height = 250;
            rect.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, 0, 0, 99));
            bm.Render(rect, null);
            bm.Invalidate();
        }

        public void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            doThings(300, 300);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your javascript onclick event handler, you try to access MainPage without registering it in the html page.

Try replacing your constuctor with this:

```
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    HtmlPage.RegisterScriptableObject("MainPage", this);
}
```

As for me, I also had to change the event subscription code in order to get it work properly:

```
document.getElementById('go').addEventListener('click', function () 
{
    slCtl.Content.MainPage.doThings(300, 300);
});
```

Comment: I already had the `RegisterScriptableObject` in `App.xaml.cs`, I tried putting it in the constructor as you suggested but that didn't make a difference. As for [`addEventListener`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff975245\(v=vs.85\).aspx), that doesn't exist in legacy IE versions.

Comment: Figured out that I had to remove the registration from App.xaml.cs. Thanks!